# Reduce the amount of decimals positions using bash printf without rounding

Tags: bash, floating-point, printf

I am using printf to restrict the amount of decimal places of a number to 3 decimal places

```
printf "%.3f\n" 8.577772
8.578
```

I want to truncate this number to 3 decimal places WITHOUT rounding up so that it prints as 8.577.

Solutions with printf are preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is a variable, which can have any number of places before the decimal:

```
$ var=8.577772
$ printf "%s.%.3s\n" $( echo $var | tr '.' ' ' )
8.577

$ var=134.56789
$ printf "%s.%.3s\n" $( echo $var | tr '.' ' ' )
134.567
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it's impossible to restrict rounding because printf uses IEEE 754 for its inner representation.
Use regexp instead:

```
echo "34234.23423423" | grep -oE '[0-9]*\.[0-9]{3}'
```